# How do you find the bounds of integration for the area bounded by a polar curve with no graph

Tags: calculus

not sure how to find the bounds of the integral for this:

Find the region enclosed by the cardioid:

r= 2+2cos(θ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you instead want to find the area of a circle of radius $R$ using integration with polar coordinates. I am aware you have probably memorized the equation for the area of a circle, however I think this derivation is useful for pedagogical purposes.

We set up our double integral like so:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^R r \, dr \, d\theta$$

The bounds for integration of $\theta$ are $0$ and $2\pi$ because we wish to rotate once around the circle. The bounds for integration of $r$ are $0$ and $R$, because at each angle during our rotation, we wish to accumulate the length from $0$ to the boundary of the circle (in polar coordinates, the equation of the circle is $r = R$).

Once we're set up, the integral is quite simple to evaluate:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^R r \, dr \, d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2} R^2 \, d\theta = \pi R^2$$

and out falls our familiar formula for the area of a circle! The situation for your cardioid is much the same, only your upper bound for integration of $r$ is no longer a constant.

Hint: The integral for the cardioid is not quite as easy to evaluate (you'll get some trig functions), but if you want to check your work, I believe the cardioid has area $6\pi$.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) regarding quality standards.